# Creating new sum and percent columns in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following data set:

```
Locations      Occupation
001            Teacher
001            Fireman
002            Teacher
002            Policeman
002            Fireman
003            Teacher
003            Teacher
003            Fireman
003            Policeman
```

I would like to create three additional columns in SAS for each location: total employed, percent police, and percent fireman. The updated data set should look like the following:

```
Locations      Occupation    TotalEmployed   PercentPolice   PercentFireman   
001            Teacher                   2               0             .50
001            Fireman                   2             .50             .50
002            Teacher                   3             .33             .33
002            Policeman                 3             .33             .33
002            Fireman                   3             .33             .33
003            Teacher                   4             .25             .25
003            Teacher                   4             .25             .25
003            Fireman                   4             .25             .25
003            Policeman                 4             .25             .25
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the output include multiple observations per LOCATION if the statistics are at the LOCATION level?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sql` to get the summary statistics and then merge with original data:

```
proc sql;
create table summary as 
select locations, count(*) as totalemployed, 
    sum(occupation='Policeman')/calculated totalemployed as percentpolice,
    sum(occupation='Fireman')/calculated totalemployed as percentfireman

from chk1
group by locations;
quit;

data final;
merge chk1 summary;
by locations;
run;
```

[image]